# Save TextBox value in a class

Tags: c#

First of all, I'm new to this website so I am very sorry if my question is not the best.
I'm learning C# in school and working on a small task in C# Forms. As a part of the task I have a text box in the Design window where the user needs to write it's name: [image]

The name of the TextBox in my project is "textBox1".

After that, I have a simple `playerManager` class:

```
 class playerManager
    {
        public string name;

        public playerManager(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

I want to make it so that what the name the user writes in the TextBox will be saved in my class, but I'm not sure how to approach this and I would be happy to receive some help. I think I need to use a constructor but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We invite you to rake the [tour] and some tips on [ask], and be able to provide a [mcve].
Regarding your question, you need to get the Text property from you input control. Can you show some code of the UI control itself?

Comment: We don't have enough code so it's a bit difficult for us to "reproduce" your problem and help you. Can you include some more context and the C# code dealing with the form/textbox? How is your textbox related to `PlayerManager`? Are you creating an object of `PlayerManager` in the form's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start to learn a right way. OnChange events  had been  used a long long time ago. You need to bind your textbox to the property.

Start from NotifyPropertyChanged handler class. Create a ViewModelBase class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
....

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

now is your class

```
public class PlayerManager:ViewModelBase
{

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            // do not trigger change event if values are the same
            if (Equals(value, _name)) return;
            _name = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
```

and finally  the binding

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    
var source = new PlayerManager();

textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", source, "Name");

//you can init string as well, if you want
source.Name="Add Name";

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but what is the "INotifyPropertyChanged" class that you've used in the first code? I mean what does it do and what is supposed to be in this class?

Comment: Create ViewBaseModel class and add  using System.ComponentModel at the top.

Comment: What version net are you using? And what is your project winforms or wpf?

Comment: The project is winforms. and I think I'm using the newest version net but I'm not very sure

Answer (score 0):

You need function which will handle an event that will be raised after user change text in text box.

Simply put in your class this function :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      name = textBox1.Text;
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=net-5.0)

[EDIT]
As @Persistence mentioned you need to also point your control textBox1 to this function (event handler), so it will be able to handle that event. You can do this in your constructor in this way (this mechanism is also called subscribe of event).

```
   this.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```

Comment: Don't forget he'll also have to point his control to this method as the event handler

Comment: first of all thank you Samuel and Persistence. When I use your code and write textBox1 I get an error saying that this name dosen't exist in the current conext. do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: That's weird name of text box is really textBox1? Did you placed function textBox1_TextChanged inside of class which represents Form in which is textBox1 located? Is your class playerManager in same file as is code for Formular - Form ?